# How to disable optimistic UI updates in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

Is it possible to disable optimistic UI in react-admin or is it configurable at runtime?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disable undoable property in Edit component:

```
<Edit undoable={false} title={<EditTitle />} actions={<EditActions />} {...props}>
```

Comment: is there a way to set `undoable={false}` for all forms globally? Thanks

Comment: create your own component based on Edit component and set undoable property to false by default

Comment: yeah I thought of that I would expect that I could just pass undoable={false} in <Admin>

Comment: if you want to have your undoable always to be false, create an Edit component with the undoable props set to false, and instead of importing the Edit component from react-admin all the time, you import your newly created Edit component.

Comment: I want to turn optimized rendering off for a Show page too, but passing `undoable={false}` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you know `undoable` cannot be set on `Create` component. Here is a way to handle optimistic rendering if your `props` are different from the `Create` page rather than disabling it.

This is an example of handling optimistic rendering on `<Show/>`:

```
const ItemShow = (props) => {
  const record = props;
  return (
    <Show
      {...props}
    >
      <ItemCreatedScreen />
    </Show>
  );
};

const ItemCreatedScreen = ({ record }) => {
  if (record.isFromCreatePage) {
    return <Loading />;
  } else {
    return <ItemView record={record} />;
  }
};
```

The custom prop `isFromCreatePage` from the form of the `Create` component should help you decide if the prop is indeed from the Create page.

Optimistic Rendering will send the request to the API after a few seconds, meanwhile, the UI can show the `<Loading/>` sign, which is for a very short duration I might add. After which the request fetches the data from the server and this can be passed on to the `<ItemView/>` page.